# nvidia geforce4 mx 440 dual using 1 male to 2 female vga splitter

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, vga

I recently got an old Graphics card nvidia geforce4 mx 440 from on of the Computers Dad was throwing out, and I am having troubles setting up dual screen for my computer, I went out and brought a VGA male to 2 VGA female cable today to try and get the dual screen working, but I got a double output of the same display on both monitors, my question is, how can I get my dual screen to work.

The board has a single VGA port, and a Circular cable of sorts, my computers board has a VGA port embedded into it.

I'm wondering if I need to change a setting in my Control Panel for NVIDIA or do I plug on screen into the card, and the other into the motherboard.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

The mx-440 only supports a single output so you won't be able to run 2 outputs of it alone (Unless you convert the s-video but not sure it will power both outputs at once)

You can run off both the MX-440 and a on-board Graphics if you motherboard supports it.

---

## Why doesn't the splitter work?

Well it does work perfectly, It split each single input into two outputs.

The easiest way for me to show this is with one of these:

[image: Water Splitter]

If you feed water into the base it will split into 2 streams. Both of these streams are still water 1 doesn't become milk because it is only taking a single input and then splits it in 2

The exact same principle applies to that splitter you bought it will take the 15 individual inputs and split them into 30 outputs

Comment: Thats also what I was trying to do, how can I get it the board to read one monitor, and display on the card as well?

Comment: Start with providing the basics, What OS are you running? What are you using to control these settings?

Comment: Win XP with sp3, what do you mean by what am I using?

Comment: You should be using a software package to control your displays, commonly either windows or nvidia

Comment: I'm using nvidia to control em

Comment: First I would try setting it up using the windows display settings as it's more likely to have drivers for both the PCI and the On-Board GPU

Comment: You'll need to set it up with the Windows Display settings. Nvidia Control Panel won't be able to see the built-in GPU unless that's also a Nvidia GPU.

Comment: I already have the drivers that are needed for the board.

Comment: Its not a nvidia gpu